# Using VSTS with multiple Azure Environments

Tags: integration, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

We are new to VSTS and will be using the online service and integrating with our production Azure AD tenant.  Since we do development that involves Office 365, this meant that we have both production and development Office 365/Azure AD environments.  We understand that our authentication can only be tied to one of these (which is fine) but can we use VSTS to perform tasks against both environments (e.g. staging, deploy, etc.)?  Are there certain things that do/don't work we should consider or are there other suggestions on how we would leverage VSTS across these environments as we take code tested against development to production?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this would be using powershell and service principal authentication. No point in copy\pasting documentation so I'll leave a link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal

You can also just authenticate to the API, get oAuth token and do pretty much anything with that. Not super straight forward, but can be done ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple azure service endpoints, then deploy app through release, simple steps:

1. Refer to this blog: [Automating Azure Resource Group deployment using a Service Principal in Visual Studio Online](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/) to manual configure [Azure service endpoint](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/service-endpoints#sep-azure-rm) (Manual Configuration section)
2. Create a [Release Definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/) in vsts
3. Add environments (e.g. Staging, Deploy)
4. Add [Azure App Service Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment) task for each environment
5. Specify corresponding Azure Subscription for these tasks